# I Need to display the content on label with multi line

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am displaying data on UIlabel for iphone  with multi-line.  the problem is that i need to display specific content and the display dot... on label if content is not display in two line after content

Comment: Please can you provide some additional explanation with you question; for example what do you want to display, versus what you are actually seeing?

Answer (score 1):

For get a multi-line label use `UITextView` or set your label to multi-line:

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 5; //Or whatever you want
```